# Django, actual month in queryset

Tags: django, django-models

how ill, get my register based in the current (actual) month in my queryset?, i have a ModelManager(), that just show the LIVE register status, but now i want to show the register with LIVE status and in the current (actual) month, i know that ill make something like .filter(...), but i dont know how get the current month..

```
model.py

#manager
class LiveNoticiaManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LiveNoticiaManager,self).get_query_set().filter(status=self.model.LIVE_STATUS)
```

thanks guys.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month

You can

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(mydatefield__year=today.year,
                           mydatefield__month=today.month)
```

Comment: That should be rewritten as MyModel.objects.filter(... the model itself doesn't have a filter method.

Answer (score 0):

That's if you are only interested in gettting the month:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

months = ['zero','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

current_month = months[today.month]
```

Comment: That's if you are only interested in gettting the month.....Hope it helps.